# Using Twitter API to embed tweets with URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to embed tweets in my app by passing in a tweets URL. I'm completely inexperienced with APIs and need a bit of guidance to set it up. Twitter has some documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) and [here](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/pro-tip-for-embedding-tweets-use-the-oembed-api-endpoint) on how to do it using Oembed. The part I'm unclear on is how to make a request:

"Make a request to the following URL for each Tweet ID, where {tweet_id} represents the value changing in a programmatic loop:"

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.{format}

Also unsure on where to add the API keys Twitter gives me. Sorry for the broad question, very new at this.